# UKVI language requirement for tier 2 visa

Tags: uk-visa, ielts, language-test

According to UKVI website, most of the Tier-2 visa applicants(including me!) should sit for an IELTS exam.

I have already taken both academic and general exams in a test centre that is on the list of UKVI SELT and again according to the UKVI documents, all facets of this test centre are acceptable.
[image: UKVI SELT]

But I have seen in other documents that only IELTS for UKVI is acceptable here which made me to believe that “**All Facets**” in above list means : IELTS for UKVI Academic and IELTS for UKVI General! Is that right?

Does that mean that I should sit for a new IELTS test, this time a UKVI one?

Answer (score 1):

For future seekers,

After April 2015, only IELTS for UKVI is accepted for Tier-2 visa. So if you have a normal IELTS TRF you should sit for an IELTS for UKVI even if you have already taken a test in one of the SELT centres.